# What is the equivalent to replace() method in JavaScript in IE before version 9?

Tags: javascript, replace

I need to use the replace() method in a script but it doesn't work in Internet Explorer before version 9 !

So the following code returns 'Visit Microsoft' also in IE < 9 !

```
var str="Visit Microsoft!";
var n=str.replace("Microsoft","Sara");
```

Comment: Try with a regexp: `var n=str.replace(/Microsoft/,"Sara");`

Comment: @DavidThomas Sorry it was a mistake and I edited it!

Answer (score 0):

`replace()` works in most of the browsers (AFAIK also IE6, IE7).

By the way, you can use this function to implement it from scratch.

http://phpjs.org/functions/str_replace/

Comment: why would anyone want to implement PHP functions in JS?!

Comment: Why not? There are a lot of people behind the PHPjs project.

Comment: because IMNSHO most PHP APIs are hideously badly "designed".